# How to prevent Oculus Home taking over Cordova+React VR app when inserted to Gear VR

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, oculus, react-360

I have a React VR app which is wrapped with Cordova to have it available as an actual app on Android device. However, when ever I insert my device into the Gear VR Oculus Home launches and takes over from the app.

There appears to be something in Unity that can sign the app so that Oculus Home lets it run, but I seem to be running low on information how to do that on Cordova.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was needed was Samsung specific `meta-data` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. For inserting the tag, I ended up using `cordova-custom-config` plugin, like so...

In main `config.xml`, under android platform tag, add...

```
<custom-config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
    <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode" android:value="vr_only" />
</custom-config-file>
```

...and you should be good to go.

Also, you might need to add `osig` file (Oculus signature file), not sure anymore if this was required.